# Dynamic ui-sref inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have created a custom directive in my Angular app which includes a couple of `ui-sref` links. I want this links to change according to the current `state`, or template being loaded:

```
<toolbar-admin page="vm.page"></toolbar-admin>
```

My intention is to pass this information through an attribute so that the links will be generated based on the `page` variable, as such:

```
<div id="toolbar" class="col-xs-12 no-pad border-bottom">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav no-collapse">
      <li class="no-collapse">
        <a ui-sref="admin.view({page: vm.page})" role="button"><span class="melon-icon-md melon-icon-back"></span></a>
      </li>
    <li class="no-collapse">
      <a class="toolbar-title" lang-tag="ProjectOverview">Project Overview</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right force-right no-collapse">
    <li class="no-collapse">
      <a ui-sref="admin.edit({page: vm.page})" role="button"><span class="melon-icon-md melon-icon-edit"></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, a `console.log` of `scope.page` within the directive will output the exact string `"vm.page"` instead of the page number that I want.

Here's the directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('melon')
        .directive('toolbarAdmin', directive);

    function directive() {
        var directive = {
            templateUrl: 'app/shared/directives/toolbar/toolbar.admin.html',
            scope: {
                page: '='
            },
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: 'true',
            link: linkFunc,
            controller: Controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true
        };

        return directive;

        function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.page = attr.page;

            console.log(scope.page);
        }
    }

    Controller.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams'];

    function Controller($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;
    }
})();
```

How can I correctly pass the page variable to the `toolbar-admin` directive?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be worry about the assignment of scope.page inside your directive controller as you have use `page: '='`. That means you enabled two way binding `vm.page` & directive `page` variable.

```
function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
   scope.page = attr.page;
   console.log(scope.page);
}
```

As your linking seems overriding actually binded value by `attr.page` which would be `vm.page`. And you are reassigning that variable to `scope.page`

If you remove the `link` function will fix your issue of binding inside your directive.